# Vector co-linear to a line in Projective plane?

Tags: geometry, vectors, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am dealing with projective plane and I am missing some basics. I would like to ask a specific question, but any resources and hints that might make me get the general idea are welcome. 
I quite get what is going on, but sometimes in my lectures I see some formulas that I do not know from where they come from and I cannot figure them out by myself and get very pissed.

So here is the question:

1. First the statement in my lectures:

   - We have a line *a* with the common equation: *Ax+By+C=0*
   - We have a vector  *p(q,s)*
   - In order the vector *p* to be co-linear to line *a* the following must be true: `q*A+s*B=0`

2 The actual question

From where comes this dependence? Why is *C* irrelevant in this case? How can I find this dependence by myself? Where I can find information about such dependencies, I could not find the answer with google?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The term “co-linear” seems inappropriate in this context. “Parallel” would be better.

Comment: I tough so too, but that is what is written in my lectures.

Comment: I suppose that it could be considered colinear if points at infinity are identified with vectors. If so, then the condition just says that the point at infinity which corresponds with $p$ satisfies the equation of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation $\;qA+sB=0$ means the vector $\vec p$ is orthogonal to vector $\vec n(A, B)$, which is *normal* to the line with equation $Ax+By+C=0$.

All lines with such an equation share this normal vector $\vec n$, hence they're all parallel, whatever $C$.

B.t.w.: what has this question to do with projective space? Everything happens in the affine plane.

Comment: You are right it's affine plane, it's beacuse I am still in the introductory part where they explain how we get homogeneous coordinates.
So if understand correctly we are getting the perpendicular vector to the perpendicular vector of line *a* thus getting a parallel vector? (I omitted the terms orthogonal and normal by purpose to simplify the statement)

Comment: Also from where does this statement come that n is normal to the line. I hate when I don't understand the source of the statement. How is this proven?

Comment: This is because if $(x_0,y_0)$ is another point on the line, the equation can be written as $\; Ax+By=Ax_0+By_0\iff A(x-x_0)+B(y-y_0)=0$, which means $\vec n$ is orthogonal to the vector with coordinates $(x-x_0,y-y_0)$.